# interface thermal printer with 8051

Tags: microcontroller

I want to interface a thermal printer with an 8051 microcontroller. The thermal printer has a DB25 parallel port. I didnt get the information regarding device driver of thermal printer.
 The printer I am using is a cbm-1000.

RM - probably: [Citizen CBM1000 printer as per manual here](http://www.goodson.com.au/download/manual/cbm/user/CBM1000%20User%20Manual.pdf)

The only information I have available is :

- (1).  Write the byte to the Data Port.
- (2).  Check to see is the printer is busy.
  If the printer is busy, it will not accept any data,
  thus any data which is written will be lost.
- (3). Take the Strobe (Pin 1) low. This tells the printer that there is the correct data on the data lines. (Pins 2-9)
- (4). Put the strobe high again after waiting approximately 5 microseconds after putting the strobe low. (Step 3)

Kindly help me on this project

---

```
setb p1.5 busy 
bit P1.5 strobe 
bit P1.4 port

Data equ P2 

org 0h 

start:   
call word_Welcome 
call enter call word_Lab     
call enter 

quit:   sjmp Quit 

Printchar: 
mov portData,A 
jb busy,$ 
setb strobe 
clr strobe 
acall delay 
Setb strobe 
acall delay 
ret 

delay: 
mov R7,#90 
del1:   
mov R6,#50 
DJNZ R6,$ 
DJNZ R7,del1 
ret 


word_welcome: 
mov DPTR,#Text_welcome 

lagi1:  
clr A 
movc A,@A+DPTR 
cjne A,#'$',Print1 
sjmp Out1 

Print1:
call Printchar 
inc dptr 
call delay 
sjmp lagi1 

Out1:   
ret  

word_Lab: 
mov DPTR,#Text_lab 

lagi2:  
clr A 
movc A,@A+DPTR 
cjne A,#'$',Print2 
sjmp Out2 

Print2: 
call Printchar 
inc dptr 
call delay 
sjmp lagi2 

Out2:   
ret  

Enter: 
mov A,#0dh 
call printchar 
call delay 
mov A,#0ah 
call printchar 
ret 

Text_welcome:   
DB 'aWelcome To$' 

Text_Lab:   
DB 'Computer Laboratory$' 
end
```

Comment: Some more information is needed on the printer. What have you tried already? We need this before we can help you.

Comment: I added a manual link below. When asking questions like this it helps if you provide links to information you have available. Most people (including me) would not have had any ida at all what a CBM1000 was. Also, telling us what you have tried and what you know technically about the equipment helps us help you. Hopefully my manual link will help.

Comment: **VERY IMPORTANT** - IF your printer DOES have a DB25 connector it is probably a serial "RS232" version. Both parallel and serial versions exist - see the manual link that I have provided. If it is a serial version then the parallel protocol that you have provided is probably not the correct one to use. Please provide more identifying information about your printer to help establish whether it is a serial or parallel port version.

Comment: @Russell - The parallel interface mentions 36 pins, so it looks like it indeed may be using the serial interface (in which case all is quite different)

Comment: @shoaib khan - please look at code above and correct any errors and advise us when done. Thanks. I have not tried to follow code at this stage, Where did you get this =code from?

Comment: @Oli Glaser - yes - the Parallel version is shown as having a Ye Olde Centronics connector and the serial versuon as having a DB25 and he said DB25 so serial seems likely but certainly not certain. He needs to provide more information on mdel detail and why he thinks it is parallel version. Note "ComputerLaboratory" txt at end of code.

Answer (score 1):

**SUMMARY**

- Link to 170+ page manual below
- See pseudo code for writing to printer below
- BUT see note at end of this answer - you printer may be a serial and not parallel interface  version !!!

---

You can download a complete [Citizen CBM1000 printer manual here](http://www.goodson.com.au/download/manual/cbm/user/CBM1000%20User%20Manual.pdf) . This provides much useful information. (173 pages in English  + about 40 in German.

You description of the interface protocol sounds adequate to allow data transfer IF you interpret it slightly differently that it is written.

Can you please provide more details about what difficulties you are having.

---

Here is how I would interpret the data writing instructions.
 NB this interpretation MAY be wrong.

- Initialisation
  Set strobe pin high
- For each data character follow the following steps.
- Step1: 
  Write data to data port.
  Check busy line.
  If      busy line is set, repeat step 1.
  else, if busy line is not set perform step 2.
- Step 2
  Set strobe pin low
  Wait 5+ microseconds
  Set strobe pin high.

---

**VERY IMPORTANT** - (This note can be rewritten in due course to make it a general comment)

IF your printer DOES have a DB25 connector it is probably a serial "RS232" version.

Both parallel and serial versions exist - see the manual link above.

If it is a serial version then the parallel protocol that you have provided is probably not the correct one to use.

Please provide more identifying information about your printer to help establish whether it is a serial or parallel port version.

Comment: this is the code im using for thermal printer

Comment: setb p1.5
 busy  bit P1.5

strobe   bit P1.4 
portData equ P2  

 org 0h
start: 
 call word_Welcome 
 call enter   
 call word_Lab   
 call enter        
 
quit: sjmp Quit         

Printchar:
 mov portData,A
 jb busy,$
 setb strobe
 clr strobe
 acall delay
 Setb strobe
 acall delay
 ret

delay:  mov R7,#90
del1: mov R6,#50
 DJNZ R6,$
 DJNZ R7,del1
 ret

Comment: word_welcome:
 mov DPTR,#Text_welcome
lagi1: clr A
 movc A,@A+DPTR
 cjne A,#'$',Print1
 sjmp Out1
Print1: call Printchar
 inc dptr
 call delay
 sjmp lagi1
Out1: ret   

word_Lab:
 mov DPTR,#Text_lab
lagi2: clr A
 movc A,@A+DPTR
 cjne A,#'$',Print2
 sjmp Out2
Print2: call Printchar
 inc dptr
 call delay
 sjmp lagi2
Out2: ret   

Enter:
 mov A,#0dh
 call printchar
 call delay
 mov A,#0ah
 call printchar
 ret

Text_welcome: DB 'aWelcome To$'
Text_Lab: DB 'Computer Laboratory$'

end

Comment: That's not particularly readable like that :-) could you edit your question and use the code tags please?

Answer (score 1):

Please tell us what you have already tried. A code sample, schematic, 8051 part number/datasheet may be useful too.

From the (pretty well written) manual Russell kindly provided, it seems the printer defaults to compatibility mode on startup, which seems to be a one way (host -> printer) 8-bit parallel interface intended for sending commands.
From there you can change to "Nibble mode" (2 x 4-bit sent consecutively) or "Byte Mode" bi-directional 8-bit parallel (requiring host to be able to change pin direction)
Page 162 gives details of the startup procedure in compatibility mode and the following pages describe operation in either nibble or byte mode.

There a some DIP switches mentioned and tables describing their actions you may want to check.
Note electrical characteristics of input/output signals described on page 30 which mention CMOS levels, 50k pullup to Vdd for data and 3k pullup for all other signals on twisted pair.

Edit - looks like serial interface may be being used. [Here](http://www.interfacebus.com/Design_Centronics_Connector_PinOuts.html) is a page on the *parallel* Centronics interface for comparison purposes.
[Here](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/layer_1/cables/tech_rs232.htm) is a page on DB25 *serial* interface.

Comment: thx alot for your sincere help